# Android activity refreshes itself instead of going to intended activity

Tags: android, eclipse, camera, android-activity

I have 2 buttons in an activity. One is a logout button which works fine and the other is a camera button which when clicked should lead to another activity. But when I click the camera button to go to the next activity(camera feature), the current activity just refreshes itself and each time I click it is an extra time i have to click the logout button to logout!(i.e if I click camera button 5 times I have to click the logout button 5 times to logout). This is probably something really stupid but I am new to programming so bear with me! Here are the relevant code snippets. If anyone can help i would really appreciate it.

**Welcome class**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class Welcome extends Activity {

// Declare Variable
Button logout;
Button cameraButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);  

    // Retrieve current user from Parse.com
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    // Convert currentUser into String
    String struser = currentUser.getUsername().toString();

    // Locate TextView in welcome.xml
    TextView txtuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtuser);

    // Set the currentUser String into TextView
    txtuser.setText("You are logged in as " + struser);

    // Locate Button in welcome.xml
    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);        

    // Logout Button Click Listener
    logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        /** Called when the user clicks the Logout button */
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Logout current user
            ParseUser.logOut();
            finish();
     }

 });

 // Locate Button in welcome.xml
    cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);

    // Camera Button Click Listener
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    /** Called when the user clicks the Camera button */
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Send user to Camera.class
        Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Camera.class);
         startActivity(intent);

    }


  });

    }
  }
```

**Button code in welcome xml layout file**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/CameraBtn" />
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:allowBackup="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.LoginSignupActivity" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.Welcome" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.Camera">
    </activity>

</application> 
</manifest>
```

**strings xml file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

<string name="hello">myapp</string>
<string name="app_name">myapp</string>
<string name="Username">Username</string>
<string name="Password">Password</string>
<string name="LoginBtn">Login</string>
<string name="SignupBtn">Sign Up</string>
<string name="LogoutBtn">Log Out</string>
 <string name="CameraBtn">Camera</string>
<string name="Welcome">Welcome!</string>  
<string name="tap">Tap the image to open the camera!!</string>
<string name="title_camera">My Message</string> 
</resources>
```

**LoginSignup class**

```
public class LoginSignupActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
Button loginbutton;
Button signup;
String usernametxt;
String passwordtxt;
EditText password;
EditText username;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.loginsignup);
    // Locate EditTexts in main.xml
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    // Locate Buttons in main.xml
    loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

    // Login Button Click Listener
    loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Retrieve the text entered from the EditText
            usernametxt = username.getText().toString();
            passwordtxt = password.getText().toString();

            // Send data to Parse.com for verification
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernametxt, passwordtxt,
                    new LogInCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                // If user exist and authenticated, send user to       Welcome.class
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        LoginSignupActivity.this,
                                        Welcome.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Successfully Logged in",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        "No such user exist, please signup",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
    // Sign up Button Click Listener
    signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Retrieve the text entered from the EditText
            usernametxt = username.getText().toString();
            passwordtxt = password.getText().toString();

            // Force user to fill up the form
            if (usernametxt.equals("") && passwordtxt.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please complete the sign up form",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(usernametxt);
                user.setPassword(passwordtxt);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // Show a simple Toast message upon successful registration
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Successfully Signed up, please log in.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Sign up Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

  }
 }
```

**ParseUser.logout**

```
 // Locate Button in welcome.xml
    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);        

    // Logout Button Click Listener
    logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        /** Called when the user clicks the Logout button */
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Logout current user
            ParseUser.logOut();
            finish();
     }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I had extends MainActivity instead of extends activity in my camera class!!

Answer (score 0):

**Button**

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/logout"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:onClick="sendMessage"
android:text="@string/CameraBtn" />
```

The `android:onClick="sendMessage"` line says that when the button is clicked, a `sendMessage` method should be called.  I would remove this line from your code unless you have a `sendMessage` method.

**Intents**

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Camera button */
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Send user to Camera.class
    Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Camera.class);
     startActivity(intent);

}
```

`new Intent(Welcome.this, Camera.class)` is an acceptable way to start a new activity.  By using `Welcome.this` instead of `this`, you are properly grabbing the context.

Comment: I have removed android:onClick="sendMessage" and changed my intent to "Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Camera.class); startActivity(intent)" as well as adjusting my manifest(as shown above) but I am still having the same problem!!

Comment: @ Phillip - I have added the entire loginsignup class with the ParseUser details

Comment: I don't seem to have a ParseUser.logOut()

Comment: You use it in the logout button listener's `onClick` method.

Comment: Found it, I've included it in the bottom of the question!

Comment: Yes, but did you write the `logOut` method for `ParseUser`?

Comment: No, is ParseUser.logOut() not a method thats included with the import statement 'com.parse.ParseUser;'???

Answer (score -1):

I have to put this as an answer because I need more reputation points to comment. 
You basically have two onClick events for the one button so you may want to fix this.

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"

 // Camera Button Click Listener
cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

And it is sometimes better to use getApplicationContext()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Camera.class);
startActivity(intent)
```

Try to modify your onClick methods to the following

```
// Add a click listener to perform action when button is clicked
         cameraButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick( View view )
                {
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have removed android:onClick="sendMessage" and changed my intent to "Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Camera.class);
startActivity(intent)" as well as adjusting my manifest(as shown above) but I am still having the same problem!!

Comment: Can you post xml for logout button please?

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/LogoutBtn" />

Comment: Have a look above. I changed onClickListener() to View.OnClickListener()